# How can I reverse an algorithm to find which string generates a specific output?

Tags: perl

I want to make a function in Perl that calculates what elements of an array to multiply to get a given value.

The array contains the integers from 559 to 574, inclusive. The value I want to get is 3552907293224.

How can I do this?

---

The idea is to get the 7-character string that produces the number 3552907293224 with this code:

```
sub hash {
     my $nr = 13;
     for (split //, shift) {
          $nr = $nr * 43 + index("acdegijmnoprstuw", $_);
     }
     return $nr;
}
```

I managed to figure out by trial and error that the string is "eddigjo", but I need a function that does this.

Comment: This might be a naive approach, but I'd start by finding which array elements go into your target value evenly. You can use the modulo operator `%` for that.

Comment: That's a pretty big problem, with a nasty complexity :). Count the appropriate permutations mathematically, by any assumption of how many multiplications you need.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Oh, yes, that does help!  May solve it easily.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the function to indicate the values used to do the multiplication, or those values' indices within the array?

Comment: Are you really interested in these particular numbers only? Or was this just an example? (Or something else entirely?) Partitioning a number is difficult, but for reasonable, practical cases, it isn't. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question, which invalidates all the work people did to answer it. Don't do that. If you realize you asked the wrong question, post a new one. You can link to the original question if you think it's relevant.

Comment: Just for completeness: the question @ThisSuitIsBlackNot refers to is http://stackoverflow.com/q/35814627/5830574

Answer (score 1):

Nice go. By [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) algorithm: None of the numbers in the given range divide the given number evenly so it is not possible to obtain it by multiplying just these.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $num = 3552907293224;

my @range = (559..574);

my @divs = grep { $num % $_ == 0 } @range;

if (@divs) {  print "Divisors: @divs\n";    }
else       {  print "No divisors found.\n"; }

# Check explicitly (lay our eyes on them)
for (@range) { print "res = " . ($num / $_) . "\n" }
```

We can make these input so different numbers can be tried but the question was specific to these.  Once the divisors are found, then you need to go through all permutations, of all possible lenghts, checking the multiplication result.  We are talking about factorial complexity.  For small ranges it will work, and there are reductions, but for longer ranges of smaller numbers it will explode quickly.

It is an interesting mathematical and computational problem to run this with good performance.

---

*The problem got clarified, and it is now a bit different: reverse the process that got to the result.*

The result is the final element in a series that starts at 13 and is generated by the given algorithm. It is driven by an additional input string, with each next character's index providing the offset. We need to reverse the process.

So work backwards.  Take the result and subtract from it the index of the last char of the input string (in the given reference string), then divide by 43.  This is our last factor. Now subtract from it the index of the one-before-last char of the input string and divide by 43, this is our next-to-last factor. Repeat until we hit 13.

```
$result = 3552907293224;
$refstr = 'acdegijmnoprstuw';
$str = 'eddigio';

for (split '', reverse $str) {
    $result = $result - index($refstr, $_) ) / 43;
    print "$result\n";
}
```

This prints

```
82625751005
1921529093.02326
44686723.0005408
1039226.00001258
24168.0000002925
562.000000006802
13.0000000001582
```

This is the process, confirmed by the fact that we got to 13 in the end.

---

*The problem evolved further and is now a different [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814627/how-do-i-reverse-this-hashing-function), with a nice answer.*

Answer (score -1):

From what I can understand from your question, you're after something like this...
My example is coded in Java, but I'm sure you get the idea!

```
public String getMultiplicationElements(int[] values, int toGet)
{
    //loop for first value in multiplication
    //will only move to next element when multiplied by all values within array
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        //loop for second value in multiplication
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++)
        {
            //test if matches specified value
            if ((values[i] * values[j]) == toGet)
            {
                //return indication of successful elements
                return "Array indices " + i " and " + j
                        + " multiply to get this result";
            }
        }
    }
    //for if no match found
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to multiply more than two numbers in that range to get that product.