# How do I reverse this hashing function?

Tags: perl

The idea is to get what is the 7 characters long string that produces this number: 3552907293224 with this script:

```
sub hash {
     my $nr = 13;
     for (split //, shift) {
          $nr = $nr * 43 + index("acdegijmnoprstuw", $_);
     }
     return $nr;
}
```

I managed to figure out the string it's "eddigjo" (with manual trying), but I need a function that reverse traces what could possibly genereate the number mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bite, even though you put no effort into solving the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

my @alphabet = split //, "acdegijmnoprstuw";   #/
sub reverse_hash {
    my ($n) = @_;

    my @letters;
    while ( $n > 43 ) {
        unshift @letters, $alphabet[$n % 43];
        $n /= 43;
    }

    return join '', @letters;
}

say reverse_hash(3552907293224);
# eddigjo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a newbie in Perl and I was trying to figure this out for two days, but i didn't get anywhere with my solutions, thats why I asked here.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to know what attempts you have made since they weren't included in the question.